# Stream 2DTexture from a 3DCamera to a Web Server / HTML Website (an iFrame)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As in the title, I am trying to achieve this to then stream the feed to a different Unity client.
Honestly, I've searched through everything on the internet, and yet not found a single example that would solve my problem. Any ideas on how to achieve it? Or where to start at least.

Thanks in advance.

C# -> Javascript/Html

Answer (score 0):

Technically, below is the complete workflow in two parts.

networking:

1. host a node.js server, with socket.io
2. Unity: create a websocket connection, stream the raw frame byte[] to socket.io server
3. socket.io server redirect the data to HTML client
4. HTML: create a javascript receiver for websocket byte[]

encoding & decoding:

1. Unity: camera -> render texture -> texture 2d -> encode as jpg
2. HTML: load the raw byte[] jpg as based64 string, and pass the value into javascript image component

Of course it's hard to find a single example online, as it takes months to solve it.

As alternative & in urgent need, you may also take a look on the plugin FMETP STREAM, which does exactly what you need with source code in C#. It could be a good reference & example.

PS: not sure if this can help, this is a step-by-step tutorial of setting up socket.io server on a new computer.
https://youtu.be/Zjm5KGHyceU